# how to implement the command kill() to send a signal to a PID

Tags: c, system-calls

I have to implement the `kill()` system call in order to send a signal to a pid.
I work with a Linux machine, I'm using C.
How should I do?
Can you just make an example?

Comment: Implement where? Are you writing a kernel? There is not nearly enough information here to provide any sort of useful answer.

Comment: see https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Kill-Example.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Kill (pid,SIGKILL);
```

`pid` is the process Id of the process to which you send the signal  `SIGKILL` which can be replaced with any other signals.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question? What exactly you want to do?